# npm run-script escape user-supplied arguments with single quotes

Tags: bash, npm

My `package.json` file contains the following:

```
"scripts": {
   "run-me": "echo"
}
```

I can then run the `run-me` script, passing in a parameter (note the single quotes):

```
npm run-script run-me '$40$30$20'
```

It runs the following command (note the double quotes):

```
echo "$40$20$30"
```

Which prints

```
000
```

The command I **actually** want `npm run-script run-me` to run is the same, but with single quotes around the argument:

```
echo '$40$30$20'
```

Which will print as I expect:

```
$40$30$20
```

So I need a way to tell `npm run-script` to escape my arguments with single quotes. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternative way to achieve same purpose.

**package.json**

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "run-me": "echo $value"
    }
}
```

**result**

```
value="$40$30$20" npm run-script run-me
> echo $value    
000

value='$40$30$20' npm run-script run-me
> echo $value
$40$30$20
```